# VS code's extensions icons disappered, why?

Tags: visual-studio-code

im using vs code as mu text editor, and recently i found that icons of extensions list doesn't show!
i mean it shoulb be like this :
[VS code shows icons extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pyPr.png)

but in my VS code it's like this:
[VS code doesn't show icons of extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhXGC.png)

so , how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Because its window is too small, just **enlarge the window** than you'll see your icons.

[image]